# Is there a way to check if an interface is a part of a union type?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Is there a way to check if an `interface` is a valid member of a union `type`? Here is an example which fails when I would have hoped for it to work:

```js
type TSafeType = { [index: string]: string };
interface IMyInterface
{
    ResponseType: string;
}

const lDoesntWork: IMyInterface extends TSafeType  // ERRORS: true is not assignable to type never
    ? true
    : never = true;
const lWorks: { ResponseType: string } extends TSafeType
    ? true
    : never = true;
```

Here is an [example playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgygQwGYRuCBnKBeKHgBOAlgHYDmUAPlCQK4C2ARhAQNwBQoksAggWQwglgGADwwAfDlhQIAD2BCAJlgAUAOk0J%20GAFxRSKAlB4BKHFIQkQUAPwmo%20khABuLTulgAlCMFoEScSlcGFkFZTVNdW0yPSgrEABtAF1zbClDFigvO2zHGld3LmgYAEkMAFlfAAsAeyVEFCDpGD4BeiERZvlFEhVYRtR0DBT2KHHcmB8-AO7wvqx4ZCHIDDGJjftCWgh1jfGnQoI9-Oc3Ng9uMowAYQAbBAwMQeaQ8qrgOobl8USAawgIFqSFgyQkHHYAGMHk8oBUQIN7o81gBvE5gYguBCKKD0AAKmOxEAAatonAxmBcNhiiFicfjCYpSQQAEz6fDEcjSABEAEZuRxqYzoPQAKokDDLZnSVQIcWSlClEhgWjAfQAMVoJEhwCItRIaQkJzR%20wmBF8-hIUFUhpOGxNpv2kP1GFqdwg6jutTIqm5ABlvWQIEpuaZBY6AL4nKPo2iMO5ESFQZ0S7Y62oEWUwTBqmgUrK4AAMpmNdomnyIGHUDNpROluAQ2fw4fGMepcYTSYA4r54QA5fOZhDqogEfBtdmEUhkUzkpjue1l8bmmZWitVmt0knaFtQNsTFXxxNQHvAeFwKfkWUjsfACd4S8zyecsilx1QdfV%20VS7SqG0WKAUQjUwbV3DYV0tD9qkrasCVrJltBZXcoxjaFkThEBvxQJFYR6CIMMRGFUXYWMjyTLCIE1bVr1Hcd%20A1LUdT1A1n2nN9HQggIoG5UU%20zgHh1QAUQFaN2BjUhFAIJAEEhaBSkGNBIHYB1xgQfRuQQbkABoTkYfRCx0jZIX0aS7gwCAdKjNDYXPZYcIwaZLQwJVJOk2Swl6fpbOwojlNIzsoDgOpaDuJQACEIEGGjb3vDlp1nKB5OWRTdkXd9OKtFT33idTNMM7Lxj0qADKXJ0TIQMyLNKqMNhQkiAHp6qgXkGO1XV9SgAARWpMCgG5qggSE-nYJBGPaq14UE7V6hYIJZXs-QYC0%20JykGRbynsl5JASuLyD88CLS47kAHVoG0aAFQgABCESY0m6alBYVRnAAdwIuyiJtZbtggMMCsdRqoD7AB5KBBK8Lxga8RbPGdegwATTBvoIHYDCwMBkWDdh7udR7M1e96fORRyAmc4QWDciAvo-FHftYKBAZBsGIahmHuDhhGiCRmnUcrKAMaeLGcZm-GIDe%20EKPs6mfr%20-6JkB8HIeh2BPHoWh8CgZgCnOTXBoQdXoC1S6gA) where I use this approach to try and validate all the method arguments and return values on a given interface/class.

Comment: Interfaces without an index signature are not assignable to object types with an index signature, while object types without an index signature are assignable. This is a difference between the two  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=20#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgygQwGYRuaBeKBvKBtASwDsATCADwC4oBnYAJ2IHMBdauxopqAXwG4AUMWAR6SBAGNoASQCyIaURFjJEAdgFQtUAEoQaYAPZEaqdOwbNBPAWQkAbBPWj2IwKAWpyFS0eKmCru5UsIgoaJBQWASCthAOTi5uUIbUuHoGxqYREBac3PwCQVDkAEzU8MhmkViGgkA What are you trying to check ? That the interface has only string members ?

Comment: I am trying to build a generic type that will check that all of a class's public methods arguments and return values can be safely `JSON.stringify`d. I can't link my typescript playground due to the link being too long, so I will attach it to the question